# Find continuous points of $f(x)=\frac{ \ln(2+\cos(e^x))}{x^2-4}$

Tags: calculus

The question is where $f(x)$ is continuous.

I know that zeros of denominator are discontinuous points and numerator should be $2+\cos(e^x) > 0$ but my teacher says that numerator is continuos from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and the domain is $(-\infty,\infty)$.

My question is how the numerator could be defined from $(-\infty,\infty)$ while its domain should be $>0$ ?

Comment: The argument of $\ln$ is always positive in this case. For every $x$. That's easy to see because $\cos$ is between $-1$ and $+1$, so numerator is between $\ln 1$ and $\ln 3$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is continuous wherever it's defined, because a composition of continuous functions (with algebraic operations).

The function is defined for $x\ne2$ and $x\ne-2$, because these values are zeros of the denominator. On the other hand, $2+\cos(e^x)>0$, because $-1\le\cos u\le 1$ for every $u$; therefore there's no limitation introduced by the logarithm.

Under the most common conventions, the domain is *not* $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Moreover, the zeros of the denominator are not zeros of the denominator; indeed
$$
\ln(2+\cos(e^x))=0
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
2+\cos(e^x)=1
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
\cos(e^x)=-1
$$
that is, if and only if $e^x=\pi+2k\pi$, that is, $x=\ln(\pi+2k\pi)$ (for $k\ge0$ integer) and neither $2$ nor $-2$ are among these values.

Therefore $f$ has asymptotes at $-2$ and $2$.

---

Surely $\pi+2k\pi>1$, so $\ln(\pi+2k\pi)>0$ and we can exclude $-2$. From $2=\ln(\pi+2k\pi)$ we get $e^2=\pi+2k\pi$. Since $e^2<9$ and $\pi+2k\pi>9$ as soon as $k>0$, this would imply $e^2=\pi$, which is false because $e^2>4$.

Comment: Just for fun, since  $2.7<e<2.72$ and $3<\pi<3.2,$ we have  $2<7/3.2<2.7^2/3.2<e^2/\pi<2.72^2/3<8/3<3$ so $e^2/\pi$ is not an integer, let alone an odd integer.......+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'd not like to compute the derivative for maxima and minima. `;-)`